# How to display plotBands by date on a Kendo chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have been trying to add plotBands by date on a kendo chart as in the snippet. plotBands doesn't seems to be at the correct position.

Note the TimeWindows object at the snippet. It should start after the first point.

tideSet is the object with Tides and TideWindows collections

How can I configure plotBands in the correct positions?

```js
    var tideSet={
                 "Tides":[
                   {
                 "timeStamp":"2018-07-24T00:33:00",
                 "pred":0.660
               },
               {
                 "timeStamp":"2018-07-24T06:09:00",
                 "pred":6.350
               },
               {
                 "timeStamp":"2018-07-24T12:32:00",
                 "pred":0.400
               },
               {
                 "timeStamp":"2018-07-24T18:51:00",
                 "pred":7.410
               },
               {
                 "timeStamp":"2018-07-25T01:19:00",
                 "pred":0.570
               },
               {
                 "timeStamp":"2018-07-25T06:58:00",
                 "pred":6.380
               }
                 ],
                 "TideWindows":[
                   {
                     "WindowsStart":"2018-07-24T02:03:00",
                     "WindowEnd":"2018-07-24T08:39:00"
                   }
                 ]
    };   
    
                
                var plots = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < tideSet.TideWindows.length; i++) {
                    plots.push(
                        {
                            from: new Date(tideSet.TideWindows[i].WindowsStart),
                            to: new Date(tideSet.TideWindows[i].WindowEnd),
                            color: "#007eff"
                        });
                }

                $("#kendoChartTides").kendoChart({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: tideSet.Tides,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    pred: { type: "string" },
                                    timeStamp: { type: "date" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: "line",
                        style: "smooth",
                        field: "pred",
                        categoryField: "timeStamp"
                    }],
                    title: {
                        text: "Tides"
                    },
                    valueAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: "Predictions"
                        }
                    },
                    categoryAxis: {
               field: "timeStamp",
                        type: "date",
                        labels: {
                     rotation: 40,
                            template: "#= kendo.format('{0:dd/HH:mm}', new Date(value)) #"
                        },
                       baseUnit:"minutes",
                        baseUnitStep: "auto",
                        plotBands: plots
                    },
                    tooltip:                  
                   {
                        visible: true,
                        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:dd/HH:mm}', new Date(category)) # <br /> Value: #= value # "
                    }
                });
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>


<div id="kendoChartTides"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the plot bands are aligned to the category axis' steps. You currently have your chart's `baseUnitStep` to `"auto"`. This causes the steps to be too far apart and your plot bands get "rounded" to the nearest steps, so to speak. Here's what you can do to work around this problem:

1. Change the `baseUnitStep` to 1. This will give you a precision of 1
   minute for your plot bands. However this will also result in grid
   lines and axis labels at an interval of 1 minute, which will be slow
   and look horrible. We'll fix that in the following steps.
2. Add a `step` value of `180` (or similar) to your labels' config. This will make the
   category labels appear every 3 hours.
3. Add a `majorGridLines` configuration section and set the step of the grid lines to `180`, so that they appear as frequently as the labels.
4. Add a `majorTicks` config section and set the step interval to `60` or something.

Your categoryAxis config section should look similar to this:

```
  categoryAxis: {
    field: "timeStamp",
    type: "date",
    labels: {
        rotation: 40,
        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:dd/HH:mm}', new Date(value)) #",
        step: 180
    },
        baseUnit:"minutes",
        baseUnitStep: 1,
        plotBands: plots,
        majorTicks: {
             step: 60
        },
        majorGridLines: {
             visible: true,
             step: 180
        }
    }
```

You can see your code snippet with these changes on this dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/EFEjezoR